# How to use REST Api or CSOM in .NET 6 client app for Sharepoint on premise

Tags: c#, sharepoint, .net-6.0, csom

In my SPA with ASP.NET Core backend, I want to create UI for uploading files that will be stored in Sharepoint 2016 hosted on premise.

I was just about to use C# CSOM, but it is only available for .NET Framework, not .NET 6.

I would use a REST API, but I can't find any sample on how to obtain authentication token. My Sharepoint site user forms based auth (username/password).

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use CSOM to connect to your SharePoint 2016 on premise server, you can use this Nuget package which still works for .NET 6 (and 7)

```
TTCUE.NetCore.SharepointOnline.CSOM
```